# Showing div boxes with different size

Tags: css

Is it possible to show divs next to each other and bellow each other instead of just bellow each other just like Google image search [google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&authuser=0&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1164&bih=563&q=hello&oq=hello&gs_l=img.3..0l10.1186.1790.0.2126.5.5.0.0.0.0.229.421.0j1j1.2.0....0...1ac.1.49.img..3.2.420.q8YCvrBwCBk), if the images were divs?

I don't think I have explained my problem clearly but thats the best I can do!

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to have images stacked next to each other that can fill the view, you could use `display:inline-block;` look at my example below:

**HTML**

```
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"><span>G</span></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"><span>O</span></div>
        <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"><span>O</span></div>
            <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"><span>G</span></div>
                <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"><span>L</span></div>
                    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"><span>E</span></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{display:inline-block;position:relative;}
span{display:block;position:absolute;top:5%;left:20%;text-align:center;font-size:80px;}
```

**For example**

http://jsfiddle.net/QJZ65/2/

**EDIT**

If you want to achieve a google image search, the div this way will expand depending on the size of the image. In this link below I updated the size of each image to show you what happens to the containers.

http://jsfiddle.net/QJZ65/3/

If you want to build a grid that uses all possible space vertically and horizontally you can try **Masonry**.

http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Does it work if div had different heights, there will be some spaces between them.

Comment: Masonry will do the trick for you, I have used it in the past and it's very versatile. I recommend it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean have a series of `Div` elements line up in a row of dynamic sizes, you could just give your `Div`s this css rule:

```
float:left;
```

Alternatively, if you set them as `inline` or `inline-block` elements, that will also accomplish it:

```
display:inline;
```

or

```
display:inline-block;
```

Comment: "float:left;" works but when there is some space left from one of the divs in top line because they have different heights the divs below don't use this space and instead just start new line when the div with greatest height in top line ends.

Comment: What do you mean by "div with greatest height in top line ends"?

Comment: Is it possible to make div boxes appear like this http://www.stumbleupon.com/interest/fashion see how different boxes with different heights are arrenged

Comment: @user3741635 Unfortunately I don't know the answer to that offhand. I think that might require javascript though. I don't think there is a way to accomplish that dynamically with CSS.